# How to get the name of nested tag from xml python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to get the name of all tags of nested tag. here is the code that I tried

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<AlternativeIdentifiers>
   <NationalLocationCode>513100</NationalLocationCode>
</AlternativeIdentifiers>
<Name>Abbey Wood</Name>
<SixteenCharacterName>ABBEY WOOD.</SixteenCharacterName>
<Address>
 <com:PostalAddress>
   <add:A_5LineAddress>
       <add:Line>Abbey Wood station</add:Line>
       <add:Line>Wilton Road</add:Line>
       <add:Line>Abbey Wood</add:Line>
       <add:Line>Greater London</add:Line>
       <add:PostCode>SE2 9RH</add:PostCode>
   </add:A_5LineAddress>
 </com:PostalAddress>
</Address>
    ''', "lxml")

tags = soup.find("AlternativeIdentifiers").name 

print(tags)
```

for example, it will print **AlternativeIdentifiers** but I want the inside tag name too which is **NationalLocationCode**. I tried using the for loop but got the error.
Just for more clarification I have tried find_all and then use the for loop to traverse to get the tag name but it will print the entire tag not the tag.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invoke the `find_all` method, then you  will get the desired ResultSet.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<AlternativeIdentifiers>
   <NationalLocationCode>513100</NationalLocationCode>
</AlternativeIdentifiers>
<Name>Abbey Wood</Name>
<SixteenCharacterName>ABBEY WOOD.</SixteenCharacterName>
<Address>
 <com:PostalAddress>
   <add:A_5LineAddress>
       <add:Line>Abbey Wood station</add:Line>
       <add:Line>Wilton Road</add:Line>
       <add:Line>Abbey Wood</add:Line>
       <add:Line>Greater London</add:Line>
       <add:PostCode>SE2 9RH</add:PostCode>
   </add:A_5LineAddress>
 </com:PostalAddress>
</Address>
    ''', "xml")

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.name)
    print(tag.find('NationalLocationCode').name)
```

**Output:**

```
AlternativeIdentifiers
NationalLocationCode
```

Comment: I want the tag names not the entire tags just the name AlternativeIdentifiers and NationalLocationCode

Answer (score -1):

when you define the *soup* variable like this the tag names get changed.
try to print *soup* variable you will get your answer.

do `print(soup)` once

Comment: I want the first tag and the tag inside that tag thats it